# Android: Reading the HTML from a website and posting it to the screen

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, sdk

I'm aiming to make a very basic application which reads the HTML and stores it into a string. I'm only interested in one line from the website's source. I found a topic which suggested this:

```
String bodyHtml = "null";
            try {
                String myUri = "http://www.spring8.or.jp/ext/ja/status/text.html";
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(myUri);

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

                // Build up result
                bodyHtml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            url.setText(bodyHtml);
```

With url being my textview. I have set the permissions in the manifest correctly as far as I'm aware.

However when I run this code on my phone and the emulator, it doesn't seem to work at all. I get nothing. Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: are you getting any error in logcat? and have you add this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in AndroidMainfest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the EntityUtils

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        response.getEntity().getContent()));
String line = "";
String newLine = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    newLine = newLine.concat(line);
}
System.out.println(newLine);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies everyone. I've tried this on the emulator and it indeed does work. However it doesn't seem to work on my physical Galaxy S2, even though it's connected to the internet. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What happens exactly? The whole app just crashes all of a sudden or all you get is an empty TextView?

Comment: No, the application doesn't crash. Instead of getting the HTML source like the emulator does, I just get the null value which I assigned before attempting to retrieve the HTML source.

Comment: Have you added the INTERNET permission to Manifest. If you have, then delete it and add again using the Android Manifest editor.

Comment: I have definitely done this and it is not in the application section. I really have no idea what could be causing this :(

Comment: So are you able to get the Http response ? Is the issue assigning the response string value to the textView ? If so just see if you have declared TextView properly in the layout. Sometimes we have a tendency to interchange TextView and EditText

Answer (score 0):

In the execute method of the [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html), also put a [`HttpContext`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext.html) as you see below:

```
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get, localContext);
```

And also use a [`BufferedReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

```
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

If it doesn't work, you'll probably have a problem with you Internet connection.
BTW, don't forget about the android.permission.INTERNET permission!

Comment: Thank you very much, it works in my emulator. I added a question to the first response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Call the below method to download the HTml Content and pass the Url in the parameter,

```
private void downloadText(String urlStr) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", 
                "Download Text from " + urlStr);
        final String url = urlStr;

        new Thread () {
            public void run() {
                int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
                InputStream in = null;
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.what=1;
                try {
                    in = openHttpConnection(url);

                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
                    int charRead;
                      text = "";
                      char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

                          while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
                          {                    
                              String readString = 
                                  String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);                    
                              text += readString;
                              inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
                          }
                         Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("text", text);
                            msg.setData(b);
                          in.close();

                }catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                messageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }.start();    
    }
```

This the helper method which returns InputStream Object,

```
private InputStream openHttpConnection(String urlStr) {
    InputStream in = null;
    int resCode = -1;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
            throw new IOException ("URL is not an Http URL");
        }

        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpConn.connect(); 

    resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();                 
    if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                 
    }         
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return in;
}
```

And now display the String in a textView using Handler,

```
private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {

            case 1:
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview01);
                text.setText(msg.getData().getString("text"));
                break;
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
```

Provide the **INTERNET** permission in the manifest.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works in my emulator. I added a question to the first response.